# Can't download xml from sharepoint with silverlight.

Tags: c#, silverlight, webclient

**EDIT:** Switched to Silverlight 4 and that got me a little further.

I have an xml that stores high scores in a sharepoint library.  The sharepoint site is https and I can hit the "copy shortcut" of the xml and it appears in a browser so I know I can get to it.

I am trying to pull this xml in using a webclient in silverlight as follows.

```
Uri url = new Uri("https://server/HighScores.xml", UriKind.Absolute);

WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://",System.Net.Browser.WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp); 
var client = new WebClient(); 
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"); 
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted); 
client.DownloadStringAsync(url);

void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
         string xmlData = e.Result;
         HtmlPage.Window.Alert(xmlData);
    }
}
```

With this code my silverlight game pops up but a windows credentials login in window comes up immediatley.  When I enter my correct crdentials in here, as i did in the code behind I get the followig error.

e.Error {System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)}   System.Exception {System.Security.SecurityException}

Any help?

Comment: What version of Silverlight are you using?

Comment: Now I am using Silverlight 4 now, I switched it.  Getting a security exception now instead of the previous exception.

Answer (score 0):

Credentials were not implemented for the WebClient until Silverlight 4. Are you using an earlier version perhaps?

[Silverlight 4 – Credentials, we’ve got it!  Mark Monster December 2nd, 2009](http://mark.mymonster.nl/2009/12/02/silverlight-4-credentials-weve-got-it/)

**Edit:**
Since you are now getting security exceptions, there may be a problem with a cross domain access policy file. Here are  couple of links that describe the two types of client access policy files that Silverlight/WebClient will look for.

[URL Access Restrictions in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008%28VS.95%29.aspx)

[Network Security Access Restrictions in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

If you have control of https://server/HighScores.xml you shouldn't have much trouble implementing a client access policy file.

Comment: Hmm this could be it.  I looked and I am compiling in Silverligth 3.  I have no option for four in my project-> options menu.  If I need Silverlight 4 it wold have to be installed on the sharepoint server as well?

Comment: I tried both techniques int he link you rprovided and I get the same security exception detailed above.